# How do you run operations on another thread in flutter?

Tags: multithreading, dart, flutter

I have a flutter app using the [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) plugin to retrieve coordinate data while the user types in the address. I can see some lag on the screen as I type on my phone, in my console I see an error that it *skipped an x amount of frames, and it is doing too much work on it's main thread*. I plan to switch to using an API from Google instead. I also get this error while I upload images to Firebase (I didn't restrict size yet), I've seen the error pop up randomly but mostly for these two cases. **What is the proper way to run operations on another thread in flutter?** Unless I should be doing something else.

Comment: is this in debug mode?

Comment: yes it's in debug mode - I think it's the default mode when I click the green arrow for run.

Comment: use `compute` function (from foundation library) for example

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new `Isolate` Loop corresponding to a new thread.

I suggest you read this article from [Didier Boelens](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures---isolates---event-loop/) blog which is very clear about all this concepts.